# TwiML: verbs Gather and Pause have no effect

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I am using the Twilio SDK (Java) to make a call to a U.S. mobile phone number and when the user answers the phone I want to have a TwiML file say a message and get the digit the user presses. But Twilio seems to completely ignore the *Gather* and *Pause* verbs in the TwiML. Twilio dials the phone number as expected but when the user answers the call, Twilio recites all the *Say* verbs in the TwiML below, the *Gather* and *Pause* have no effect and Twilio disconnects the call. Also although the *Say* verbs specify a woman's voice Twilio uses a male voice for these.

Is there a way to get the *Gather* and *Pause* working in the TwiML below? Is there a way to make the *Say* statements use a woman's voice?
Note that I am using a trial Twilio account.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Response>
    <Say voice="woman">This is a courtesy phone call from YourCompany.</Say>

    <Say voice="woman">Please press one to buy our products.</Say>
    <Say voice="woman">Press two to be removed from our list.</Say>

    <Pause length="5" />

    <Gather timeout="60" numDigits="1" method="POST" action="http://twimlets.com/echo?Twiml=%3CResponse%3E%3CSay%3EHi+there.%3C%2FSay%3E%3C%2FResponse%3E" >
        <Pause length="30" />
    </Gather>

    <Say voice="woman">Goodbye.</Say>
</Response>
```

Comment: If you're trying to debug, I suggest that  you do one thing at a time. Put a 'Say' first and get it working with the voice you want. Move onto 'Pause' and get it working and then fix the 'Gather'.

Comment: I'm not sure why your voice change isn't working, though I would suggest using the voice "alice" rather than "woman" as it is a more up to date voice. Also, I would recommend nesting all of your `<Say>`s and `<Pause>`s inside the `<Gather>` so that users can press as soon as they know what they want.

Answer (score 1):

I grabbed your [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) from above and dusted off my [Twilio-Java](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/java) setup (thanks)!

```
package com.twilio;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.twilio.sdk.verbs.TwiMLResponse;
import com.twilio.sdk.verbs.TwiMLException;

import com.twilio.sdk.verbs.Say;
import com.twilio.sdk.verbs.Gather;
import com.twilio.sdk.verbs.Pause;


public class StackOverflow extends HttpServlet {

    public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        TwiMLResponse twiml = new TwiMLResponse();


        Gather gather = new Gather();
        gather.setTimeout(60);
        gather.setNumDigits(1);
        gather.setMethod("POST");
        gather.setAction("http://twimlets.com/echo?Twiml=%3CResponse%3E%3CSay%3EHi+there.%3C%2FSay%3E%3C%2FResponse%3E");
        Say sayInGather1 = new Say("This is a courtesy phone call from YourCompany.");
        sayInGather1.setVoice("alice");
        Say sayInGather2 = new Say("Please press one to buy our products.");
        sayInGather2.setVoice("alice");
        Say sayInGather3 = new Say("Press two to be removed from our list.");
        sayInGather3.setVoice("alice");
        Pause hanging = new Pause();
        hanging.setLength(30);
        Say sayInGather4 = new Say("Goodbye.");
        sayInGather4.setVoice("alice");

        try{
            gather.append(sayInGather1);
            gather.append(sayInGather2);
            gather.append(sayInGather3);
            gather.append(hanging);
            gather.append(sayInGather4);
            twiml.append(gather);
        } catch (TwiMLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        response.setContentType("application/xml");
        response.getWriter().print(twiml.toXML());
    }
}
```

All that Servlet code translates to the following XML:

```
<Response>
  <Gather timeout="60" numDigits="1" method="POST" action="http://twimlets.com/echo?Twiml=%3CResponse%3E%3CSay%3EHi+there.%3C%2FSay%3E%3C%2FResponse%3E">
    <Say voice="alice">This is a courtesy phone call from YourCompany.</Say>
    <Say voice="alice">Please press one to buy our products.</Say>
    <Say voice="alice">Press two to be removed from our list.</Say>
    <Pause length="30"/>
    <Say voice="alice">Goodbye.</Say>
  </Gather>
</Response>
```

Hope you'll find this helps. If you're curious for even more examples of using the `<Gather>` verb with Java, [check out the tutorials](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/ivr-screening/java/servlets#4).

Comment: Thanks, but I am aware of this way of building up the TwiML in Java code. It is cumbersome and a pain to maintain. So I would prefer to have the TwiML hosted on my server.

Comment: Cool, just thought I'd leave both for context. Hope you got it working for your needs.